# Rails Active Record Query Breaking When Switching To PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi all I get this error:

```
column "article_tags.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

when I switched to PostgreSQL with this query:

```
@article_tags = ArticleTag.includes(:tag, :article).where(is_deleted: [nil, false]).where('tags.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.category_id' => @category.id).group('tags.slug').order('tags.articles_count DESC')
```

I have tried fixing it with a selecting only the associated records like so:

```
@article_tags = ArticleTag.includes(:tag, :article).where(is_deleted: [nil, false]).where('tags.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.category_id' => @category.id).select("tags.*").group('tags.slug').order('tags.articles_count DESC')
```

however the specific SELECT is ignored.

It never broke when using MySQL. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"? This issue has come up hundreds of times.

Comment: Yes and I tried those solutions but they did not seem to work.

Comment: Then include the attempted solutions and results in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I have solved my problem in a suitable way. Basically I got rid of includes and group. I instead used joins and selected distinct columns. Below is my final query if anyone else runs into these problem(s):

```
@article_tags = ArticleTag.select("DISTINCT (tags.slug), tags.articles_count").joins(:tag, :article).where(is_deleted: [nil, false]).where('tags.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.is_deleted' => [nil, false], 'articles.category_id' => @category.id).order('tags.articles_count DESC')
```